# "Unexpected error" when trying to create a mint account on React

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, typescript, phantom-wallet

I am using @solana/spl-token to create a minting account on a react typescript application. When the following code work to send a normal transaction, the instruction SystemProgram.createAccount, once send to Phantom wallet, and validated send back an error to the app:

```
   at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (chunk-NDJPXGNU.js?v=e601c535:1838:15)
   at async chunk-NDJPXGNU.js?v=e601c535:2448:12
   at async createMintAddress (MintSolana.tsx:43:31)
```

Here is my React typescript component code:

```
import { useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import SolanaWalletButton from "../../elements/SolanaWalletButton/SolanaWalletButton";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { clusterApiUrl, Connection, Transaction, SystemProgram, Keypair } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { useState } from "react";

const MintSolana = () => {

    const { publicKey, sendTransaction, connected, signTransaction } = useWallet();
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    const createMintAddress = async () => {

        if (!connected || !publicKey || !signTransaction) {
            console.log('Wallet is not connected');
            return;
        }

        const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
        const MINT_SIZE = 82;

        // Get the minimum balance required for the mint account to be rent-exempt
        const rentExempt = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(MINT_SIZE);

        // Create a transaction to fund the mint account and create the mint
        let transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: Keypair.generate().publicKey,  // Create a new keypair for the mint account
                lamports: rentExempt,
                space: MINT_SIZE,
                programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            })
        );

        const {
            value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight }
        } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

        try {
            const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection)
            await connection.confirmTransaction({ blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight, signature });
            console.log("TX CONFIRMED!", signature);
        } catch (error: any) {
            setError(error);
            console.error(error);
        };
    };


    return <>
        <div>Mint on Solana</div>
        {connected ? (
            <>
                {error && <div>Error! {error.toString()}</div>}
                <div><button onClick={createMintAddress}>Create Mint Address</button></div>
            </>
        ) : (
            <SolanaWalletButton></SolanaWalletButton>
        )}

    </>;
}

export default MintSolana;
```

Thanks for your time.

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign with the keypair of the new account, but this code just throws away the new keypair. You can instead do:

```
        let newAccount = Keypair.generate();
        // Create a transaction to fund the mint account and create the mint
        let transaction = new Transaction().add(
            SystemProgram.createAccount({
                fromPubkey: publicKey,
                newAccountPubkey: newAccount.publicKey,  // Create a new keypair for the mint account
                lamports: rentExempt,
                space: MINT_SIZE,
                programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            })
        );
```

And then later use that keypair to sign:

```
            const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, { signers: [newAccount] })
```

Assuming that I've understood how this version of `sendTransaction` works, using these props: https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/blob/78c74624e497780864533a00d6e07e965a6d8f4d/packages/core/base/src/adapter.ts#L23